# Running Capybara test in Github action in UI mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, github-actions

Failure/Error: visit url

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
     (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
     (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

This is my github workflow

```
name: CI Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ github_actions_test ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: CI
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Chrome
        uses: browser-actions/setup-chrome@latest
        with:
          chrome-version: stable

      - name: Download chrome driver
        uses: nanasess/setup-chromedriver@master

      - name: unzip and install chrome driver
        run: |
          export DISPLAY=:99
          chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub &
          sudo Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 & # optional

      - name: Setup ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@477b21f02be01bcb8030d50f37cfec92bfa615b6
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.6

      - name: Run bundle install
        run: |
          gem install bundler
          bundle install
      - name: Build and test with rspec
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/my_spec_file.rb
```

My capybara config file

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'clipboard'
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'
require 'selenium/webdriver'


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :all do
    register_selenium
  end
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end

def chrome_capabilities(chrome_options = [])
  Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: {
      args: chrome_options
    }
  )
end


def register_selenium
  browser, profile, capabilities, driver_name, js_driver_name, options = [:chrome,
                                                                            nil,
                                                                            chrome_capabilities(%w[headless disable-gpu
                                                                                                   disable-popup-blocking no-sandbox
                                                                                                   disable-dev-shm-usage]),
                                                                            :headless_chrome,
                                                                            :headless_chrome,
                                                                            Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new]
                                                                         

  Capybara.register_driver driver_name do |app|
    http_client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    http_client.open_timeout = 250
    http_client.read_timeout = 250
    driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      http_client: http_client,
      browser: browser,
      profile: profile,
      desired_capabilities: capabilities,
      options: options
    )
    driver
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = js_driver_name
  Capybara.default_driver = js_driver_name

end
```

1. Is it possible to use chrome WITH head in github actions
2. Please let me know if there is any issues with my chrome setup in github
3. should we take chrome driver path from github action setup to config file. If yes how do we get the installed path

Tried all possible things and combinations of configurations. No luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: [Thomas Walpole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2709090/thomas-walpole) any suggestions please. I managed to run in headless mode. But running in UI mode is my requirement. @ThomasWalpole